# Using a if statement in a looped table rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models, one with cards and another with their associated rewards programs. I'm showing all of them in a table with a conditional if statement in some of the columns but I can't figure out why an if else statement screws up my columns. I posted two examples one that works and one that doesn't. I need the second one to work to add some additional functionality

This example works

```
   <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Card</th>
        <th>General Rewards</th>
        <th>Gas Amount</th>
        <th>Movies Amount</th>
        <th>Museums Amount</th>
        <th>Theme Park Amount</th>
        <th>Restaurant Amount</th>
        <th>Department Store Amount</th>
    </tr>

    <% @cards.each do |card| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= card.name %></td>
        <td><%= card.general_rate %> </td>
        <% card.rewards.each do |category| %>
        <% if category.name.downcase == "gas" %>
        <td><%= category.threshold_check(@gas) %></td>
        <% end %> 
        <% if category.name.downcase == "movies" %>
        <td><%= category.threshold_check(@movies) %></td>
        <% end %> 

        <% if category.name.downcase == "museums" %>
        <td><%=  category.threshold_check(@museums) %></td>
        <% end %> 
        <% if category.name.downcase == "theme parks" %>
        <td><%=  category.threshold_check(@theme_parks) %></td>
        <% end %> 
        <% if category.name.downcase == "restaurants" %>
        <td><%=  category.threshold_check(@restaurants) %></td>
        <% end %> 
        <% if category.name.downcase == "department stores" %>
        <td><%=  category.threshold_check(@department_stores) %></td>
        <% end %> 
        <% end %>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

This adds extra columns to the end

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Card</th>
        <th>General Rewards</th>
        <th>Gas Amount</th>
        <th>Movies Amount</th>
        <th>Museums Amount</th>
        <th>Theme Park Amount</th>
        <th>Restaurant Amount</th>
        <th>Department Store Amount</th>
    </tr>

    <% @cards.each do |card| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= card.name %></td>
        <td><%= card.general_rate %> </td>
        <% card.rewards.each do |category| %>
        <td><%= category.name.downcase == "gas" ? category.threshold_check(@gas) : 0 %></td>
        <td><%= category.name.downcase == "movies" ? category.threshold_check(@movies) : 0 %></td>
        <td><%= category.name.downcase == "museums" ? category.threshold_check(@museums) : 0 %></td>
        <td><%= category.name.downcase == "theme parks" ? category.threshold_check(@theme_parks) : 0 %></td>
        <td><%= category.name.downcase == "restaurants" ? category.threshold_check(@restaurants) : 0 %></td>
        <td><%= category.name.downcase == "department stores" ? category.threshold_check(@department_stores) : 0 %></td>
        <% end %>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't see an `<% end %>` tag for `<% card.rewards.each do |category| %>` here, but that should generate a template error.

Answer (score 0):

If you will notice the main difference between your 2 versions is that the first one if your conditionals dont comply, you will not issue a `<td></td>`

On the other hand your second version does have `<td></td>` no matter if the conditionals are true or not.
Maybe that could be the source for your extra columns.

*P.S. In your first example I think you have a typo but `<%= category.threshold_check(@movies) %>` doesn't have an opening `<td>` and it's closing `</td>` is outside the if statement.*